# Where do I stick my azure connection string

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure, connection-string, asp.net-mvc-5

My publish settings were suppose to add it when I use the Import feature from azue and select the sql DB I want to use with code first? But it didn't set a connection string in my web.config should it be in my web.release.config? so confused. Here is the connection strig I got from azure, but I don't know where to put it...

> Server=tcp:xxxxemxxx1.database.windows.net,1433;Database=XXX;User
>   ID=XXXinc@xxxxemxxx1;Password=XXXXXX8XX!;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection
>   Timeout=30;

Do I replace my local default connection string? If so then why do the publish settings have me pick my SQL Server DB? I also checked under the CONNECTION tab in Publish dialogue box and everything was populated as I would expect. I switch to the SETTINGS tab in Publish and select under Databases my corresponding SQL Server and check the two boxes:

[x] Use this connection string at runtime (update destination web.config)
[x] Execute COde FIrst Migrations (runs on application start)

So far so good, everything gets uploaded and the site appears to work fine until I use the login feature (ASP.NET Identity-MVC 5). This is it's first dealing with the Database and I get the following error from the url: `https://mywebsite.azurewebsites.net/Account/Login`

> Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification
>   starting at index 0.

Here is the Stack Trace:

```
[ArgumentException: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.]
   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.GetKeyValuePair(String connectionString, Int32 currentPosition, StringBuilder buffer, Boolean useOdbcRules, String& keyname, String& keyvalue) +5314705
   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Hashtable parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean firstKey) +124
   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean useOdbcRules) +95
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(String connectionString) +59
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionOptions(String connectionString, DbConnectionOptions previous) +24
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPoolGroup(DbConnectionPoolKey key, DbConnectionPoolGroupOptions poolOptions, DbConnectionOptions& userConnectionOptions) +167
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ConnectionString_Set(DbConnectionPoolKey key) +61
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value) +66
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.InitializeFromConnectionStringSetting(ConnectionStringSettings appConfigConnection) +122
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.TryInitializeFromAppConfig(String name, AppConfig config) +32
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.Initialize() +127
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.get_ProviderName() +13
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.get_ProviderName() +11
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.DefaultModelCacheKeyFactory.Create(DbContext context) +91
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext() +499
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +18
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +53
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext() +15
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider() +38
   System.Linq.Queryable.Where(IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate) +63
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore`1.FindByNameAsync(String userName) +617
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.<FindByNameAsync>d__d.MoveNext() +102
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.<FindAsync>d__15.MoveNext() +244
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
   MYWEBSITE.Controllers.<Login>d__2.MoveNext() +244
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
   lambda_method(Closure , Task ) +23
   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.ThrowIfFaulted(Task task) +33
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +68
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass34.<BeginInvokeAsynchronousActionMethod>b__33(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +16
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3c() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass45.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3e() +225
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass30.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__2f(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass28.<BeginInvokeAction>b__19() +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1e.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1b(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__4(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +31
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9631764
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

I have wasted hours on this, I have read many questions here on StackExchange. I don't know how to check the Web.Config file that Visual Studio uploads to the Azure website in order to see if it is correct. But Azure dictates all of this in the publish settings right? It should work???

My web.config on my machine has the standard DEFAULT CONNECTION STRING:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MYWEBSITENAME-201312290500266;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-MYWEBSITENAME-201312290500266.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the Azure portal, on the configure tab :

[image: Configure tab]

And set the connection string here, it will override the `web.config` file :

[image]

**EDIT :** just saw the format of your connection string in your question.

**Yours is :**

> Server=tcp:xxxxemxxx1.database.windows.net,1433;Database=XXX;User
>   ID=XXXinc@xxxxemxxx1;Password=XXXXXX8XX!;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection
>   Timeout=30;

**Mine is :**

> **Data Source=** tcp:myServerName.database.windows.net,1433;**Initial Catalog=** myDatabaseName; User ID=
>   myUserName@myServerName;Password=myPasswordHere;

Comment: Us hats need to stick together. Trying this now.

Comment: Please note that in the screenshot the type of the connection string is "Custom". It's because I use database first. Not sure you need this with code first !

Comment: But you think I should name it DefaultConnection?

Comment: You should use the same name as in your `web.config` file. So yes : DefaultConnection.

Comment: Didnt seem to make a difference. I'm confused as to why the tutorial make no mention of the connection string. tinyurl.com/DeployAzure

Comment: Your answer makes complete sense, but I see no change. When I go to login I still see the same error which is attributed to a bad (or no) conncection string. They should really make this easier.

Comment: Sorry it doesn't work for you, I never had any problem with that but I never used the publish wizard (my site is auto deployed by [Visual Studio Online](http://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-online-overview-vs)).

Comment: I have visual studio online as well. THe only reason I used the publish settings is because it was part of the tutorial. My normal workflow is Commit locally, Push to VisualStudioOnline then publish to azure. SO maybe I should try to deploy from visual studio online

Comment: Have you checked the content of the final web.config file with an ftp client ?

Comment: No. This is my first project using Git, Visual Studio Online & Azure. I made it so far. And now The connection string rules me. Not sure how to do that.

Comment: Yep I have it configured just as you have made your edit. I am so frustrated with azure. I have another site on my own server. But the client insisted on azure.

Comment: I would be ok with changing my local connection string to the SQL Server on azure connection string if it made things work. I'm so ready for a fix. Azure has no support when it comes to problems like this.

Comment: All of the sudden Im getting this error instead:
Migrations is enabled for context 'ApplicationDbContext' but the database does not exist or contains no mapped tables. Use Migrations to create the database and its tables, for example by running the 'Update-Database' command from the Package Manager Console.

Comment: But how would my local setup know how to migrate those changes? My local connection string points to local db?

Comment: This is a CodeFirst specific question, sorry I didn't use this mode yet.

Comment: No problem. I'll eventually get it worked out. I appreciate you showing me how to add the connection string. This was useful!

Comment: I just swapped out my local connection string with my azure string and I think it's migrating. Not sure why I did not do this earlier.

Comment: So it added all my tables to the database on azure, but I still get the same error. I restarted the website and ran update-database again still nothing works. THis is a lost cause.

Comment: Can you try to upload manually by FTP your config file ? You will find the FTP address in the dashboard of your site in the Azure portal.

Comment: Got it working. I had to comitt the web.config by itself then I comitted the entire project by itself and then I finally saw the propper web.config file in visualstudioonline then I did one final update-database -force -verbose and when I went to test the login page it worked. SO for now  got it.

Comment: Yeah but that was bullcrap. I expect that if I'm deploying to azure and I use their only tutorial that is widely available through their website, that they at least get the steps right or don't leave out important information. I'm persistent. But others will just quit.

Comment: If anything I am grateful that you stuck around even though you may not have had the right answer and just shot off any idea you had to help me get there. I will try to do the same and pass the love to the next guy that needs help! You rock man! Happy new year!

Comment: @httpJunkie & httpJunkie.com if you ever need anything!

Comment: Happy to help :) Will go to sleep now :) Happy new year !

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44121/discussion-between-jyl-and-eric-b)